# How to get the com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowSession for a particular user

Tags: workflow, aem

Can anyone help me out in getting the com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowSession for a particular user. I am able to get the session for administrator but not able to get the workflow session for a user other than administrator.

For administrator we can get the session in this manner.

```
com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowSession wf =
     resourceResolver.adaptTo(com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowSession.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're in the context of a Sling HTTP request the `ResourceResolver` of the current `Resource` points to the request's user, so adapting like you do should return that user's session.

If you don't have a request context, the mechanism used in Sling's [SlingServletResolver](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/sling/trunk/bundles/servlets/resolver/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/servlets/resolver/internal/SlingServletResolver.java) should work, impersonating the `ResourceResolver` before adapting. Look for the `createAuthenticationInfo`() method definition and use in that class. I haven't tried it myself but I suppose that would work as the `ResourceResolver` then points to the desired user.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this way

```
    ServiceReference serviceReference=componentContext.getBundledContext().getServiceReference(com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowSession.class)
    com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowSession wf =(com.adobe.granite.workflow.WorkflowSession)componentContext.getBundledContext().getService(serviceReference)
```

Thanks,
Balaji.

Answer (score -1):

```
Session session = workflowSession.getSession();
```